# When I am updating JList items they get displayed in a weird way

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jlist

When I am adding items to the model List, they get displayed really weird on the `JList` and I don't know why it's really small and they overlap as well. When I am presetting a List it gets displayed normal like its setup from the `setFixedCell`, could you give me a hint?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class test{

    static JFrame mainFrame;
    static JPanel mainPanel;
    static JButton mainSwitch;
    static JList mainList;
    static long firstTime = 0;
    static long times1;
    static int i = 0;
    static boolean x = false;   
    static DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    
    // hole Inferface stuff
    test(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Zeiterfassung");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainSwitch = new JButton("ON");
        mainList = new JList(model);
        
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(420, 420);
        mainPanel.setSize(10, 10);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainList.setBounds(12, 10, 380, 300);
        mainList.setFixedCellHeight(30);
        mainList.setFixedCellWidth(30);
        mainSwitch.setBounds(12, 320, 380, 50);
        
        mainSwitch.addActionListener(e -> messureTime());
        
        mainPanel.add(mainSwitch);
        mainPanel.add(mainList);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    // Method behind the button, normal boolean that changes the text on button "startTracking"
    public static void messureTime() {
        if(x == false) {
            firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mainSwitch.setText("Stop");
            x = true;
        }
        else if(x==true){
            times1 = (System.currentTimeMillis() - firstTime)/1000;
            model.addElement(String.valueOf(times1) + "Seconds");
            mainSwitch.setText("Start");
            x = false;
            mainList.setFixedCellHeight(5);
            i++;
            mainList.setModel(model);
        }
    }   
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zeit zeiterfassung = new Zeit();
    }
}
```

Comment: suggestions 1) use a layout manager 2) Place the JList inside a `JScrollPane` to allow scrolling

Answer (score 2):

Remove this statement that is restricting the height per list cell to a mere 5 pixels

```
mainList.setFixedCellHeight(5);
```

Comment: Oh god, i overlooked that command.... thanks alot !